# copy a table row of design HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I want the moment you click on "create row", line 2 is duplicated with the formatting rule: input, select ..

In addition to the first column I want each time to exceed a count of +1 in "count number".

Once I click on Delete Row - it will let me delete the last line except line 1!

Thanks for the helpers!

this is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered table-hover" style="font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial;">
   <thead>
  <tr>
    <th style="text-align: right;">השתתפות / שוברים</th>
<th style="text-align: right;">סכ"ה ימים</th>
<th style="text-align: right;">עד תאריך</th>
<th style="text-align: right;">מתאריך</th>
    <th style="text-align: right;">שם משפחה</th>
    <th style="text-align: right;">שם פרטי</th>
    <th style="text-align: right;">מ.א</th>
    <th style="text-align: right;">number count</th>
  </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
 
   <tr class="warning">
     <td style="text-align: center;">
     
     <select style="font: 12px 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;width: 94px;margin: 0.4rem;text-align-last: right;">
  <option value="volvo">השתתפות</option>
  <option value="saab">שוברים</option>
  
  
</select>
  
     
     </td>
     <td style="text-align: right;"><input type="number" id="fname2" name="firstname" style="font: 12px 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;width: 31px;margin: 0.4rem;text-align-last: center;"></td>
     <td style="text-align: right;">
<fieldset>
    <div>
        <input type="date" name="trip" style="font: 12px 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;width: 113px;margin: 0.4rem;">
    </div>


</fieldset>
</td>
     

<td style="text-align: right;">

<fieldset>
    <div>
        <input type="date" name="trip" style="font: 12px 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;width: 113px;margin: 0.4rem;">
    </div>


</fieldset>
</td><td style="text-align: right;">
<input type="text" id="fname2" name="firstname" style="font: 12px 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;width: 55px;margin: 0.4rem;text-align: right;">

</td>
<td style="text-align: right;">
<input type="text" id="fname2" name="firstname" style="font: 12px 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;width: 52px;margin: 0.4rem;text-align: right;">

</td><td id=check style="text-align: right;">
<input type="number" name="firstname" style="font: 12px 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;width: 64px;margin: 0.4rem;text-align-last: center;">
</td>
     <td style="text-align: center;padding-top: 20px;">1
              </td>
   </tr> 
      </tbody>
 </table>
<br><br>

<p id="demo" onclick="myCreateFunction()">Create row</p> <br>
<p id="demo" onclick="myDeleteFunction()">Delete row</p>


<script>
function myCreateFunction() {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(0);  
    var cell5 = row.insertCell(0); 
    var cell6 = row.insertCell(0); 
    var cell7 = row.insertCell(0); 
    var cell8 = row.insertCell(0);
    cell1.innerHTML =  1;
    cell2.innerHTML = 2;
    cell3.innerHTML = 3;
    cell4.innerHTML = 4;
    cell5.innerHTML = 5;
    cell6.innerHTML = 6;
    cell7.innerHTML = 7;
    cell8.innerHTML = 8;
}

function myDeleteFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(-1);
}


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

functions down

Comment: What do you mean with '*exceed a count of +1 in "count number"*'? Do you want an additional increasing counter on `myCreateFunction` regardless of the number of existing rows after deletions? A count how many rows were ever created?

Answer (score 0):

A fast and easy solution (though maybe not best for long term use) is to have a global variable called something like "depth", start it at `let depth = 0` then every time you add a line `depth++;`, if you remove a line only let it remove the line `if(depth >= 0)` then you will never be deleting the starting line that already exists.

Another way to do it, and maybe more scalable if this is for a bigger project, is to keep track of the number of lines in an array, each time you add a line, you `arr.push(line);` when you remove a line you `arr.splice(indexofline,1);` This gives you the ability to not just track what line you're at, but you could also push information about the line that you could use in later code for expanding the program.

Comment: Thank you!
The problem is that I can not do it. Once I put the code in a count it is not updated.

Comment: I have it working here: https://codepen.io/dotEthan/pen/xaJvXx

You need to define the variable "count" as 0. Update it with `count++;` anytime you add a row and `count--;` anytime you take it away. I also defined the variable "depth" and did the same thing, then made it so it only deletes a line IF the depth is above 0.

Comment: Huge thanks! It works.
I have one last problem that I could no longer understand how to do this, that as soon as I want a new line I want all the contents of line 1 (input, select) - all the cells to be copied to row 2 and so on.

Comment: Sorry, not sure your question, do you mean when you add a new line you want the new line to be inserted on top of the previous lines? So the newest are at the top and the oldest at the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

You have some problems in your code.

- First of all HTML IDs have to be unique. You are using multiple identical IDs.
- Some input fields have the same name. This does not have to be a problem by all means, however, many server-side script languages (e.g. PHP) just overwrite multiple usages and expose just the last one. PHP forms arrays if you use names like `<input name="firstname[]">`.
- A non-empty `<title>My Title</title>` tag is mandatory in HTML5.

Further more

- Documents should declare the charset they are encoded with.
- It is always a good idea to have an `<html>` tag with a `lang` attribute.
- Avoid inline styles. Use stylesheets instead.
- Inline event handlers like `onclick` are old-school. Apply event listeners instead.
- There are semantical senseless `<div>` elements in the cells.
- `<fieldset>` elements containing only one field do not make semantical sense, especially when they devide two related dates. A fieldset enclosing both dates within the same cell could make sense. Use css outline or similar to get the visual effect if you need it.

To get a copy of another row, you can use the `cloneNode` method.

The number of rows can be determined with `table.rows.length`. You can use it to fill the 'number count' cell.

If you do need IDs for some reason, they have to be unique per document. This means, you need different IDs even in each row. When copying, you have to change the id in some way - e.g. append the row number.

I have added some demo `<label>` just to illustrate how to change necessary IDs and the label's `for` Attribute which is connected to the ID of the according form field. Of course a label in a column with a caption does not really make sense - it's only for teaching purposes.

Copying the first row might be a bad choice, since the entered values are copied as well. More common would be to copy the last entered row. However, there is another alternative. You can use a clean template. `<template>` elements are not rendered by the browser and thus they are not part of the DOM. You get DOM-like access via the `content` property.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', evt =>
{
  const
    minRowsPreserved = 2,
    byId             = document.getElementById.bind(document)
  ;

  function myCreateFunction()
  {
    let
      table    = byId("myTable"),
      rowCount = table.rows.length,
      row      = byId('tpl-row').content.firstElementChild.cloneNode(true)
    ;

    // In case you need IDs: Append the row number seperated by '-' to each ID since IDs must be unique.
    row.querySelectorAll('[id]').forEach(e => e.id += '-' + rowCount);
    // Similar for clickable labels depending on IDs, however, there is no shortcut for the `for` attribute.
    row.querySelectorAll('label[for]').forEach(e => e.setAttribute('for', e.getAttribute('for') + '-' + rowCount));
    // Content of the last cell becomes the row number.
    row.cells[row.cells.length-1].textContent = rowCount;
    // now we append the row to the table body after id-conflicts should be resolved
    table.tBodies[0].appendChild(row);
  }

  function myDeleteFunction() {
    let table = byId("myTable");
    if(minRowsPreserved < table.rows.length)
      table.deleteRow(-1);
  }

  byId('btn-create').addEventListener('click', myCreateFunction);
  byId('btn-delete').addEventListener('click', myDeleteFunction);

  // add a first row on start
  myCreateFunction();
})
```

```css
#myTable
{
  font-size    : 12px;
  font-family  : Arial;
  border       : 1px solid black;
  text-align   : center;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

#myTable td
{
  border : 1px solid black;
  padding: 0.4rem;
}

#myTable th
{
  text-align: right;
}

#myTable input,
#myTable select
{
  font  : 12px 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
}

#myTable input[type="text"]   { text-align     : right;  }
#myTable input[type="number"] { text-align-last: center; }
#myTable select               { text-align-last: right;  }

#myTable input[type="date"]   { width          : 113px;  }
.num1       input             { width          : 31px;   }
.first-name input             { width          : 55px;   }
.last-name  input             { width          : 52px;   }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="he">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>dynamic table form</title>

<body>

  <form method="post">

    <table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered table-hover">

      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>השתתפות / שוברים</th>
          <th>סכ"ה ימים</th>
          <th>עד תאריך</th>
          <th>מתאריך</th>
          <th>שם משפחה</th>
          <th>שם פרטי</th>
          <th>מ.א</th>
          <th>number count</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
      </tbody>

    </table>
  </form>

  <button id="btn-create">Create row</button>
  <button id="btn-delete">Delete row</button>

  <template id="tpl-row">
    <tr class="warning">
      <td class="car">
        <select id="car" name="car[]" style="width: 94px; text-align-last: right;">
          <option value="volvo">השתתפות</option>
          <option value="saab">שוברים</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td class="num1"      >  <input type="number" id="num1"       name="num1[]"      >  </td>
      <td class="trip-start">  <input type="date"   id="trip-start" name="tripstart[]" >  </td>
      <td class="trip-end"  >  <input type="date"   id="trip-end"   name="tripend[]"   >  </td>
      <td class="first-name">  <input type="text"   id="first-name" name="firstname[]" >  </td>
      <td class="last-name" >  <input type="text"   id="last-name"  name="lastname[]"  >  </td>
      <td class="check">
        <label for="num2">demo label:</label>
        <input type="number" id="num2" name="num2[]" style="width: 64px; text-align-last: center;">
      </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </template>
```

Comment: Thank you!
How do I now do that the content in line 1 will also be creating new lines?

Comment: @ShahafShefer please be more specific. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: When I click "Create Row," I create a new row with the same data that I had in row 1.
Example picture of how I want him to see: http://i.imgur.com/WKpFFge.png

Comment: I've created a remake with explanations according to your comments.