# Copy elements to a new row in the current table

Tags: javascript, html

My code is here: [https://codepen.io/dotEthan/pen/xaJvXx](http://%20https://codepen.io/dotEthan/pen/xaJvXx)

When I click "Create Row," I create a new row with the same data that I had in row 1. Example picture of how I want him to see: [i.imgur.com/WKpFFge.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffrLY.png)

Thx for helpers!

Comment: What is the problem? Just set `cell.innerHTML` proper values like `<input...`

Comment: it's dosnt work... try in the link that I send here up ^

Comment: I did and it works. Make sure that there is no new lines in values.

Comment: you can please to send me how it's work for u?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [copy a table row of design HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52345512/copy-a-table-row-of-design-html)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow (SO). Please do not spam SO with multiple identical questions. If you want to add something, you can use the edit function below your questions. This site is meant to host unique questions and answers. Codes should be included directly into the question, not linked to other hosting platforms. When you get more reputation, you will be able to promote your questions with bounties.

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem? Just set `cell.innerHTML` proper values like `<input...`.
This works.

```js
let depth = 0;
let count = 0;

function myCreateFunction() {
  var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  var row = table.insertRow(-1);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell4 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell5 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell6 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell7 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell8 = row.insertCell(0);
  cell1.innerHTML = 1 + count;
  cell2.innerHTML = '<input type="number" name="firstname" style="font: 12px \'Fira Sans\', sans-serif;width: 64px;margin: 0.4rem;text-align-last: center;">';
  cell3.innerHTML = '<input type="text" id="fname2" name="firstname" style="font: 12px \'Fira Sans\', sans-serif;width: 52px;margin: 0.4rem;text-align: right;">';
  cell4.innerHTML = '<input type="text" id="fname2" name="firstname" style="font: 12px \'Fira Sans\', sans-serif;width: 55px;margin: 0.4rem;text-align: right;">';
  cell5.innerHTML = '<fieldset><div><input type="date" name="trip" style="font: 12px \'Fira Sans\', sans-serif;width: 113px;margin: 0.4rem;"></div></fieldset>';
  cell6.innerHTML = '<fieldset><div><input type="date" name="trip" style="font: 12px \'Fira Sans\', sans-serif;width: 113px;margin: 0.4rem;"></div></fieldset>';
  cell7.innerHTML = '<input type="number" id="fname2" name="firstname" style="font: 12px \'Fira Sans\', sans-serif;width: 31px;margin: 0.4rem;text-align-last: center;">';
  cell8.innerHTML = '<select style="font: 12px \'Fira Sans\', sans-serif;width: 94px;margin: 0.4rem;text-align-last: right;"><option value="volvo">השתתפות</option><option value="saab">שוברים</option></select>';
  depth++;
  count++;
}

function myDeleteFunction() {
  if (depth > 0) {
    depth--;
    count--;
    document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(-1);

  }
}
```

```css
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered table-hover" style="font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="text-align: right;">השתתפות / שוברים</th>
      <th style="text-align: right;">סכ"ה ימים</th>
      <th style="text-align: right;">עד תאריך</th>
      <th style="text-align: right;">מתאריך</th>
      <th style="text-align: right;">שם משפחה</th>
      <th style="text-align: right;">שם פרטי</th>
      <th style="text-align: right;">מ.א</th>
      <th style="text-align: right;">number count</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr class="warning">
      <td style="text-align: center;">

        <select style="font: 12px 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;width: 94px;margin: 0.4rem;text-align-last: right;">
          <option value="volvo">השתתפות</option>
          <option value="saab">שוברים</option>
        </select>


      </td>
      <td style="text-align: right;"><input type="number" id="fname2" name="firstname" style="font: 12px 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;width: 31px;margin: 0.4rem;text-align-last: center;"></td>
      <td style="text-align: right;">
        <fieldset>
          <div>
            <input type="date" name="trip" style="font: 12px 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;width: 113px;margin: 0.4rem;">
          </div>


        </fieldset>
      </td>


      <td style="text-align: right;">

        <fieldset>
          <div>
            <input type="date" name="trip" style="font: 12px 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;width: 113px;margin: 0.4rem;">
          </div>


        </fieldset>
      </td>
      <td style="text-align: right;">
        <input type="text" id="fname2" name="firstname" style="font: 12px 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;width: 55px;margin: 0.4rem;text-align: right;">

      </td>
      <td style="text-align: right;">
        <input type="text" id="fname2" name="firstname" style="font: 12px 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;width: 52px;margin: 0.4rem;text-align: right;">

      </td>
      <td id=check style="text-align: right;">
        <input type="number" name="firstname" style="font: 12px 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;width: 64px;margin: 0.4rem;text-align-last: center;">
      </td>
      <td class="count" style="text-align: center;padding-top: 20px;">1
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br><br>

<p id="demo" onclick="myCreateFunction()">Create row</p> <br>
<p id="demo" onclick="myDeleteFunction()">Delete row</p>
```

Comment: tnx! but if I will do this: 
cell1.innerHTML = <center>1 + count</center>; It's dosnt work again. I want that the number count will be center like row 1.

Comment: `cell1.innerHTML = '<center>'+(1 + count)+'</center>';`